# The ng2-go-top-button is not working in angular 5

Tags: angular, scroll, scrolltop

I installed ng2-go-top-button module using

**npm install ng2-go-top-button --save**

and imported it in appmodule and using the selector tag (***ng2-go-top-button***)
in the HTML file in project. I am not getting any error and i am unable to see the button any where on page.

i am using angular cli ver 1.6.5
angular ver 5.2

The below coded is used in HTML

```html
<body>
      
            <h2 align="center">Testing Page</h2>
    <br>
            <form [formGroup]="criticalDatesForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSub()">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="70%" align="center">
                    
                        <go-top-button [html]="'<i class=\'fa fa-arrow-up\'></i>'"
                            [animate]="true"
                            [speed]="50"
                            [acceleration]="2"
                            [scrollDistance]="20"
                            [styles]="{
                               'border-radius': '20px 20px 20px 20px',
                               'right': '5px',
                               'color': 'green',
                               'border': '5px solid',
                               'line-height': '20px'
                            }">
             </go-top-button>

                    <tr>
                        <pre>
                                NPR’s text.npr.org is likely the oldest example of a working text-only news site that’s still in existence. It originally launched as thin.npr.org back in June 2005, in response to the September 11th attacks — when many news sites struggled to stay online amidst record traffic numbers — and also to help people who were navigating to npr.org back in 2005 on handheld mobile devices like Blackberries.

                                Earlier this month, a number of improvements were made to the site (which redirects to thin.npr.org) aimed specifically at low-bandwidth users. 
                                
                                “More recently, our full site [npr.org] has made major accessibility gains,” write Patrick Cooper, NPR’s director of web and engagement, and Sara Goo, the managing editor of digital news. “But as accessible or as fast as you can make your full site —and speed is critical for us — low-bandwidth situations are a different challenge. [Our] improvements focused on those users in particular.”
                                
                                Text.npr.org’s improvements included  “adding a caching layer to greatly improve speed and adding code to make the site display well on phones,” write Cooper and Goo. “We also increase[d] the number of stories on the [text.npr.org] homepage, made the homepage use the story ordering from our full site, updated the navigation links, removed an interim page in each story that showed only the first paragraph (something that was more valuable before we improved the page speed), and created an easier to remember “text.npr.org” redirect for the site.”
                                
                                In recent months, Twitter, Facebook, and Google News have also published their own versions of stripped-down sites that use less bandwidth, mainly aimed at users in emerging markets who might not have access to faster network connections. Earlier this week, Twitter announced that it was now experimenting with an Android app designed to use less data for people with limited connectivity.
                                
                                Yet most news organizations — aside from CNN, NPR, and The Age in Australia — don’t have low-bandwidth sites versions of their sites.
                                
                                There are many ways that news organizations can improve the ways they serve both low-bandwidth users and people with visual impairments by stripping out unnecessary elements and optimizing different parts of a website. To learn more, I reached out to front-end website designer J. Albert Bowden, who frequently tweets about accessibility and web design standards, to ask a few questions about how we might approach building text-only sites to help end users.
                                
                                Kramer: I’m curious. What kinds of things can be stripped from sites for low-bandwidth users and people with visual impairments?
                                
                                Bowden: Those are two very distinct user groups but some of the approaches bleed over and can be applied together.
                                
                                For low-bandwidth users: Cut the fluff. No pictures, no video, no ads or tracking. Text files are good enough here. Anything else is just fluff.
                                
                                For visually impaired users: I’m going to just talk about a11y [which is a shorthand way of referring to computer accessibility] here.
                                
                                A11y is best addressed in the foundation of a website, in the CSS, HTML, and JavaScript. There are other ways to go about doing it, but they are much more resource intensive and therefore are never going to be default for mainstream.
                                
                                Typical user agents for those with visual impairments are screen readers, which rely on the foundation (literally HTML) of a website to interpret its content and regurgitate it back to the user.
                                
                                Kramer: Is text-only the way to go? Are there ways to think about preloading images and/or other methods that might help these users?
                                
                                Bowden: Text in HTML is the way to go here; you cover accessibility issues and SEO bots, while simultaneously also being usable on the maximum number of devices possible. HTML and CSS are forgiving in the sense that you can make mistakes in them, and something will still be rendered to the user. Browsers are 

                                NPR’s text.npr.org is likely the oldest example of a working text-only news site that’s still in existence. It originally launched as thin.npr.org back in June 2005, in response to the September 11th attacks — when many news sites struggled to stay online amidst record traffic numbers — and also to help people who were navigating to npr.org back in 2005 on handheld mobile devices like Blackberries.

                                Earlier this month, a number of improvements were made to the site (which redirects to thin.npr.org) aimed specifically at low-bandwidth users. 
                                
                                “More recently, our full site [npr.org] has made major accessibility gains,” write Patrick Cooper, NPR’s director of web and engagement, and Sara Goo, the managing editor of digital news. “But as accessible or as fast as you can make your full site —and speed is critical for us — low-bandwidth situations are a different challenge. [Our] improvements focused on those users in particular.”
                                
                                Text.npr.org’s improvements included  “adding a caching layer to greatly improve speed and adding code to make the site display well on phones,” write Cooper and Goo. “We also increase[d] the number of stories on the [text.npr.org] homepage, made the homepage use the story ordering from our full site, updated the navigation links, removed an interim page in each story that showed only the first paragraph (something that was more valuable before we improved the page speed), and created an easier to remember “text.npr.org” redirect for the site.”
                                
                                In recent months, Twitter, Facebook, and Google News have also published their own versions of stripped-down sites that use less bandwidth, mainly aimed at users in emerging markets who might not have access to faster network connections. Earlier this week, Twitter announced that it was now experimenting with an Android app designed to use less data for people with limited connectivity.
                                
                                Yet most news organizations — aside from CNN, NPR, and The Age in Australia — don’t have low-bandwidth sites versions of their sites.
                                
                                There are many ways that news organizations can improve the ways they serve both low-bandwidth users and people with visual impairments by stripping out unnecessary elements and optimizing different parts of a website. To learn more, I reached out to front-end website designer J. Albert Bowden, who frequently tweets about accessibility and web design standards, to ask a few questions about how we might approach building text-only sites to help end users.
                                
                                Kramer: I’m curious. What kinds of things can be stripped from sites for low-bandwidth users and people with visual impairments?
                                
                                Bowden: Those are two very distinct user groups but some of the approaches bleed over and can be applied together.
                                
                                For low-bandwidth users: Cut the fluff. No pictures, no video, no ads or tracking. Text files are good enough here. Anything else is just fluff.
                                
                                For visually impaired users: I’m going to just talk about a11y [which is a shorthand way of referring to computer accessibility] here.
                                
                                A11y is best addressed in the foundation of a website, in the CSS, HTML, and JavaScript. There are other ways to go about doing it, but they are much more resource intensive and therefore are never going to be default for mainstream.
                                
                                Typical user agents for those with visual impairments are screen readers, which rely on the foundation (literally HTML) of a website to interpret its content and regurgitate it back to the user.
                                
                                Kramer: Is text-only the way to go? Are there ways to think about preloading images and/or other methods that might help these users?
                                
                                Bowden: Text in HTML is the way to go here; you cover accessibility issues and SEO bots, while simultaneously also being usable on the maximum number of devices possible. HTML and CSS are forgiving in the sense that you can make mistakes in them, and something will still be rendered to the user. Browsers are 
                        </pre>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please show us the code of your module and your HTML.

Comment: have you updated your systemjs.js file

Comment: @JulienAmbos i have updated my question with code sample. please check.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale we are using WEB PACK no systemjs.js is required i think.

Comment: Did you add ng2-go-to-top-button to your compilation output as described in https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-go-top-button#angular-cli--150-issue ?

Comment: @JulienAmbos i tried that too. But didn't work.

Comment: I don't think any other html elements are allowed inside a `table` as the direct child but `<tr>`. Please move it outside the table or inside a `<td>`.

Comment: Got it. There is problem with one css class where i specified <position: Absolute;> Once i removed that everything works fine inside the table also. Anyways thanks for your help. :-)